# How to move focus on next cell in a datagridview on Enter key press event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Friends, I'm working on windows application using C#. I'm using a datagridview to display records. The functionality I need is when I press "Enter" key the focus should go to the next cell(column of same row). If it's the last column in the grid then the focus should go to the first column of the next row. I've already tried using

```
    SendKeys.Send("{Tab}")
```

in datagridview1_KeyDown and datagridview1_KeyPress event. But focus is moving diagonally down. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    int iColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    int iRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    if (iColumn == dataGridView1.Columncount-1)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.RowCount > (iRow + 1))
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, iRow + 1];
        }
        else
        {
            //focus next control
        }
    }
    else
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[iColumn + 1, iRow];
}
```

Comment: It's working but not 100%. When first time the grid is populated then I select the first cell.After that I press "Enter", now focus is going to the second row(though I have 4 columns). And also after reaching the last cell(last row,last column), it's giving error as "Index out of range"..

Comment: Ya.. I know that.. I was quiet hurry at that time. so i didnt complete that.. You can also write code when you reach the last row and then if u need an new row to be created u can create then

Comment: I accepted your answer on very 1st day itself..both of your solutions helped me to solve my problem..So next day I accepted Amrit's answer also..Can't I accept more than 1 answer?

Answer (score 11):

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
{
    int icolumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    int irow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {                                
        if (icolumn == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, irow + 1];
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[icolumn + 1, irow];
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will also execute when there is a textbox on the UI,  next to the datagridview, when you press Enter on the textbox.

Answer (score 6):

you can use selectionchanged event of the datagridview.
In your form

```
       private DataGridViewCell _celWasEndEdit;

        private void datagridview_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (MouseButtons != 0) return;

        if (_celWasEndEdit != null && datagridview.CurrentCell != null)
        {
            // if we are currently in the next line of last edit cell
            if (datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex == _celWasEndEdit.RowIndex + 1 &&
                datagridview.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == _celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex)
            {
                int iColNew;
                int iRowNew = 0;
                if (_celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex >= datagridview.ColumnCount - 1)
                {
                    iColNew = 0;
                    iRowNew = dgvItems.CurrentCell.RowIndex;                   
                }
                else
                {
                        iColNew = _celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex + 1;
                        iRowNew = _celWasEndEdit.RowIndex;
                }
                datagridview.CurrentCell = datagridview[iColNew, iRowNew];
            }
        }
        _celWasEndEdit = null;
      }

    private void datagridview_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        _celWasEndEdit = dgvItems[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    }
```

Comment: it is just a variable which is used to track the cell which is being edited

Comment: private DataGridViewCell _celWasEndEdit; i have written in above solution

Comment: Without editing I want to move focus from one cell to next horizontally..How will I do that?

Comment: I have used this so many times any way i recheck what we can do

Comment: 'MouseButtons', nice keyword.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool notlastColumn =true; //class level variable--- to check either last column is reached or not

private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1 == e.ColumnIndex)  //if last column
    {
        KeyEventArgs forKeyDown = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Enter);
        notlastColumn = false;
        dataGridView1_KeyDown(dataGridView1, forKeyDown);
    }
    else
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{up}");
        SendKeys.Send("{right}");
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && notlastColumn) //if not last column move to nex
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{up}");
        SendKeys.Send("{right}");
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{home}");//go to first column
        notlastColumn = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the codes I tried moved the focus to next cell, They where effecting the mouse click when the cell was in edit mode.
This is what I came up with in the end.

```
    bool _dgv_list_cellEndEdit = false; // class level variable

    void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress=true;
            SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
        }
    }

    void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        _dgv_list_cellEndEdit=true;
    }

    void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _dgv_list_cellEndEdit=false;
    }

    void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(_dgv_list_cellEndEdit)
        {
            _dgv_list_cellEndEdit=false;
            SendKeys.Send("{Up}");
            SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting a bit modified version of [@Amritpal Singhs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9666741/2794280).

If you have `hidden(Visible=false)` columns as a last column of your grid, then @Amritpal Singhs' solution will throw an error. Below solution takes into account those hidden columns and works without exception:

```
private void gridDetails_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (MouseButtons != 0) return;

   if (_lastCellEndEdit != null && gridDetails.CurrentCell != null)
   {
       // if we are currently in the next line of last edit cell
       if (gridDetails.CurrentCell.RowIndex == _lastCellEndEdit.RowIndex + 1 &&
           gridDetails.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == _lastCellEndEdit.ColumnIndex)
       {
           int iColNew;
           int iRowNew = 0;

           var lastCellEndEditColumn = gridDetails.Columns[_lastCellEndEdit.ColumnIndex];
           if (lastCellEndEditColumn.DisplayIndex >= GetVisibleColumnsMaxDisplayIndex())
           {
               iColNew = GetFirstVisibleColumnIndex();
               iRowNew = gridDetails.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
           }
           else
           {
               iColNew = GetNextVisibleColumnIndex(lastCellEndEditColumn.DisplayIndex);
               iRowNew = _lastCellEndEdit.RowIndex;
           }
           gridDetails.CurrentCell = gridDetails[iColNew, iRowNew];
       }
   }
   _lastCellEndEdit = null;

}

private DataGridViewCell _lastCellEndEdit;

private void gridDetails_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   _lastCellEndEdit = gridDetails[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
}

int GetVisibleColumnsMaxDisplayIndex()
{
   int maxDisplayIndex = -1;
   foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in gridDetails.Columns)
   {
       if (column.Visible && column.DisplayIndex > maxDisplayIndex)
       {
           maxDisplayIndex = column.DisplayIndex ;
       }
   }
   return maxDisplayIndex;
}

int GetFirstVisibleColumnIndex()
{
   var firstVisibleColumnDisplayIndex = gridDetails.Columns.Count - 1;
   var firstVisibleColumnIndex = 0;
   foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in gridDetails.Columns)
   {
       if (column.Visible && column.DisplayIndex < firstVisibleColumnDisplayIndex)
       {
           firstVisibleColumnDisplayIndex = column.DisplayIndex;
           firstVisibleColumnIndex = column.Index;
       }
   }
   return firstVisibleColumnIndex;
}

int GetNextVisibleColumnIndex(int previousColumnDisplayIndex)
{
   var nextVisibleColumnDisplayIndex = gridDetails.Columns.Count;
   var nextVisibleColumnIndex = previousColumnDisplayIndex;

   foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in gridDetails.Columns)
   {
       if (column.Visible && column.DisplayIndex > previousColumnDisplayIndex 
           && (column.DisplayIndex - previousColumnDisplayIndex) <= (nextVisibleColumnDisplayIndex - previousColumnDisplayIndex))
       {
           nextVisibleColumnDisplayIndex = column.DisplayIndex;
           nextVisibleColumnIndex = column.Index;
       }
   }
   return nextVisibleColumnIndex;
}
```