# How to use Enter key as Tab key in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

I have a `DataGridView` with 5 columns. If press Enter key in the first column, focus moves to next row. I want to move the focus to the next *column* when I press Enter key.

```
 private void dgvComp_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
    if (dgvComp.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly)
    {
       SendKeys.Send("{tab}");

    }   
 }
```

In the above code I have columns 2,3 and 4 as read only columns. If I press Tab, focus should directly go to 5th column.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move focus on next cell in a datagridview on Enter key press event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666657/how-to-move-focus-on-next-cell-in-a-datagridview-on-enter-key-press-event)

Answer (score 9):

would you pls try this solution

```
using System.Diagnostics;
class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{

    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter) {
            base.ProcessTabKey(Keys.Tab);
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }

    protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
            base.ProcessTabKey(Keys.Tab);
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: +1. This is the preferred method. Be sure to handle other relevant key combinations as well, such as Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a KeyPress event handler:

```
private void dgvComp_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyChar)
    {
        case (char)Keys.Enter:
            SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datagridview.EditingControlsShowing += datagridview_EditingControls;
datagridview_EditingControls(object sender,DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
  e.control.KeyDown += Control_KeyDown;
}
private void Control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1];
        }
    }
```