# DataGridView KeyDown Event Keys.Enter

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Please Someone Help me? My Question is: I use below code to move focus to next cell in a `DataGridView` row:

```
if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter) 
{
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    e.Handled = true; 
}
```

This is working only when a focus on a cell but if we edit in a cell "something" then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the focus are shifted below the selected cell.

Comment: if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
  {
   SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
   e.Handled = true;
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to use Enter key as Tab key in DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499282/how-to-use-enter-key-as-tab-key-in-datagridview)

Comment: my Problem is there?

Comment: i make it duplicate of Enter As a tab key its working all right when the focus on a one cell but when a cell is begin to edit and after editing or Endedit the focus will go down to current cell but i want that focus will go to the next cell on this situation please help me..................thanks

Comment: Follow the linked post and use the inherited DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MouseButtons != 0) return;

```
            if (_celWasEndEdit != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
            {
                // if we are currently in the next line of last edit cell
                if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex == _celWasEndEdit.RowIndex + 1 &&
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == _celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex)
                {
                    int iColNew;
                    int iRowNew = 0;
                    if (_celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex >= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
                    {
                        iColNew = 0;
                        iRowNew = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        iColNew = _celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex + 1;
                        iRowNew = _celWasEndEdit.RowIndex;
                    }
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[iColNew, iRowNew];
                }
            }
            _celWasEndEdit = null;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            //Invisible Column Exception
        }
    }
```