# keeping cursor within particular column of data grid view

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on windows form application..

I have a data grid view like this:

[image: enter code here]

Here I am in the driver id column I have to enter driver id. Once I enter the drive id I will press Enter button. At the same time cursor move to next column with release button, but I don't want to move my cursor there automatically, I want to keep always my cursor within the driver id column.

How i can achieve that?

Comment: you need to handle processcmdkey event in datagridview. to handle this event you have to create custom datagirdview control inherited by datagridview control.

Comment: sir i created custom datagirdview control inherited by datagridview control,,then i assinged  custom datagirdview control name to my data grid view..but that time my data grid view is not workign(not loding data to my data grid view)

Comment: sir i created new custom control class name mycustomdgv..then i wrote code in my data grid view page load event like this:  this.DGVall= new MyCustomDGV() ,,,but this time my DGVall datagrid view not working,,

Comment: Don't assign your custom datagridview control to datagirdview control placed on your windows form. direct place it to your windows form.

Comment: so i want to remove my old data grid view and replace custom datagrid view?

Comment: yes, You don't need to add that default gridview in your winform. just add your custom datagridview

Comment: i added my custom data grid view..i have to write any code in this custom grid view form?

Comment: No, it will works same as default datagridview. But, you have to write some code to keep focus drive id column in custom datagridview control.

Comment: what code i have to write to keep focus driver id column,,could you please give one example?

Comment: for example ProcessCmdKey as i have mentioned in my first comment. take a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17361803/3184380

Comment: sir in that link i checked first answer,,i wrote the same code in data grid view event,,but that is not worked for me...

Comment: It is just a logic that you can use in your datagridview to prevent focus cursor on other column on enter key.

Comment: and again i have said that use ProcessCmdKey not keydown event in your custom datagridview control

Comment: in my data grid view first two column read only..you know while i enterd driver id and i press enter key then that row will remove from the data grid view..so that time cursor is moving to next row release button,,insted of that i want to keep cursor on the first row of driver id column

Comment: sir i didnt see any ProcessCmdKey  event in my custom datagrid view properties

Comment: have you checked above link? ProcessCmdKey is not a public event that you can select it directly from the designer. you have to override it in your custom datagridview control same as given example in link.

Comment: sir,,i given code ProcessCmdKeynow see my last column is button,,if i click enter in the driver id column that moving to last column.instead of moving ther want to keep my cursor inthe same column.i given code like this:if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {                                
        if (icolumn == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, irow + 1];
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[icolumn + 1, irow];
        }
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a simple example, so you can understand how can you use ProcessCmdKey event and prevent focus cursor on other column. I have created custom **datagridviewcontrol (MyGrid)** and placed that control in my windows form.

```
//Code added in form load.
MyGrid1.KeepCursorColumnIndex = 2; //I want to keep focus on column index 2



//MyGrid custom grid class 
public partial class MyGrid : DataGridView
{
    private int _freezCursorColumnIndex = -1;
    public int KeepCursorColumnIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return _freezCursorColumnIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            _freezCursorColumnIndex = value;
        }
    }

    public MyGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
    {

        if (_freezCursorColumnIndex > -1 && this.CurrentRow != null && keyData == Keys.Return)
        {
            this.CurrentCell = this.CurrentRow.Cells[KeepCursorColumnIndex];
            keyData = Keys.None;
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

}
```

The above code is not a complete example. you need to make some changes in ProcessCmdKey code. for example if you have set KeepCursorColumnIndex to 3 and your current selected column index is 1 then you press enter the cursor will directly move to index 3 instead if column 2. another if your current row index is 1st then it will be changed to 2nd if exist.

Comment: sir this time in grid view i have to write only this code?MyGrid1.KeepCursorColumnIndex = 2;

Comment: this property will be set in form not in custom datagridview control. even you can set it at design time from property grid.

Comment: no sir ,,still i am not getting focus to driver id column

Comment: then you have done something wrong, because i have already done it in my testing project.

Comment: paste ur full code in this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48048/net-winforms-sql-cr-report

Comment: sir i created new custom control class with your above code and in windows form i added that grid view and i wrote a code in form load event like this: MyGrid1.KeepCursorColumnIndex = 2; i did only this

Comment: let's discuss in chat room. link is given above.

Comment: just open it http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48048/net-winforms-sql-cr-report

Comment: i opens ..but i havnt see my chat place

Answer (score 3):

What about keeping it as it is and user datagridview cell end edit event?

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

      if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name=="driverid")
      {

    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[(e.RowIndex+1)].Cells["driverid"];
     dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);

      }
    }
```

Is this working i have not tested as i have no data to test

Comment: what happned if user Press `TAB' or `arrow key` insted of enter ?

Comment: Ya i know @GujjuDeveloper but i added as the alternate solution if user agree with any key for datagridview

Comment: but might be it gives an error if user press arrow keys