# Manually move to next cell in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a DataGridView and I have 2 editable cells. The first cell uses a custom control and the second is a standard textbox.

The custom control has an `ItemChanged` event and this event is raised when the user enters a value in the control.

How can I subscribe to this event and how can I move to the next editable cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the custom control in the `DataGridView`'s `EditingControlShowing` event by using `e.Control`. Here an exemple with a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` :

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)e.Control).TextChanged += TextBoxCell_TextChanged;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666657/how-to-move-focus-on-next-cell-in-a-datagridview-on-enter-key-press-event):

```
private void customControl_ItemChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
            int iColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int iRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            if (iColumn == dataGridView1.Columns.Count-1)
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, iRow + 1];
            else
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[iColumn + 1, iRow];
    }
```

You'll also need to add a line to the InitializeComponent() method in FormName.Designer.cs if you can't link the event via the designer, something like:

```
this.customControl.ItemChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.customControl_ItemChanged);
```

Comment: First part will work. However, the second part won't work because the datagridview creates an instance of the custom control. It is not a control on the form.

Comment: At what point is that custom control being created then? Can you just append the subscribe line to the end of wherever you're doing the creating, or to whichever event is triggered once your datagridview is intialized?

Comment: The control itself implements `IDataGridViewEditingControl`, and I have 2 extra classes that inherit from `DataGridViewColumn` and `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`. Instantiating the custom control is handled by the `DataGridView` automatically.

Comment: Something in FormName.Shown event handler then? That'll ensure that your datagridview is fully initialized first; find the custom controls by type comparison or column and subscribe there?