# Move Caret to DataGridViewTextBoxCell when a CheckBoxCell is clicked in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've a DataGridView with 2 columns

> Column1 type: DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
>      Column2 type : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

When a Cell in `Column1` is Clicked, then Caret/Cursor should be moved to `Column2`.

Code is below, but its not working.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow _row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(_row.Cells[0].Value))
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)_row.Cells[1];
            _row.Cells[1].ReadOnly = false;
            DataGridViewCell textBoxCell = _row.Cells[1];
            if (textBoxCell != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = textBoxCell;
                dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
                ((TextBox)dataGridView1.EditingControl).SelectionStart = 0;
            }
        }   
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Zygote

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666657/how-to-move-focus-on-next-cell-in-a-datagridview-on-enter-key-press-event

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Fix your two errors: `if-statement` evaluates to `false`, but even if it passed, the next line would throw an error.
2. Cleaner concise method.

---

**1. Fixes**

The statement:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(_row.Cells[0].Value))
```

evaluates to `False` when `Value` is `null` the first time the cell is clicked.  Change this to:

```
if (_row.Cells[0] is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
```

When this evaluates to `True`, the following line throws `InvalidCastException`:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)_row.Cells[1];
```

Either:

1. Change the index 1 to 0.
2. Try `_row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`. Nevertheless `chk` will be `null`.
3. Remove the line.  You aren't using it anyways.

**2. Cleanup**

Replace your entire method:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
  {
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1];
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
  }
}
```